# When I create a new project by using npm create vite@latest and do npm install, I get the following error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, vite, semantic-versioning

semver  <7.5.2
Severity: moderate
semver vulnerable to Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-c2qf-rxjj-qqgw
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install eslint-plugin-react@7.25.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/eslint-plugin-react/node_modules/semver
eslint-plugin-react  7.19.0 || >=7.26.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of semver
node_modules/eslint-plugin-react

2 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

If I use npm audit fix --force, it shows 0 vulnerabilities but then after running npm audit fix --force, when I try to install other packages it shows me again many vulnerabilities.

please help

Answer (score 0):

update the eslint-plugin...that might help:

`npm install eslint-plugin-react@latest`

Comment: or use yarn instead

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Have already tried this but still get the same message of vulnerabilities. This started happening after I included the airbnb style guide